# как в конец текста добавить изображение,что бы оно не смещало текст

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, изображения, текст

есть текст в конц которого надо добавить изображение[image: троеточие]

```
 <div class="article__text">
<p>
  фывфывфывфывфывфывфывфывфывфывфывфывфыв
   фывфывфывфывфыв<span><img class="linkDetail"src="/img/Link__Detail.png
</span> 
     </p>
  </div>
```

так как верстку начал изучать не давно столкнулся с проблемой(скорее всего не очень
серьёзный,однако решить ее не получается)
нужно вставить изображение в конец текста так что бы оно не смещало верхнюю строчку текста

[image: пример того как быть не должно]

ожидается что то такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы можете уменьшить размер изображения до размера текста.

Comment: на макете изображение должно быть таких же размеров(

Comment: Выкладывай весь код как у тебя такое рисуется уж если спрашиваешь, где img находится внутри <p> или за? или ты его как-то через css вставляешь.? А так вообще картинка будет занимать часть блока это по любому.

Comment: Было бы не плохо, если вы показали, как в макете. Тогда было бы более понятно, что ожидается.

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: Три точки надо добавить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы разместить картинку в строке, не обязательно оборачивать `img` в `span`. Для этого существуют css свойство `display` и его значения `inline` и `inline-block`(legacy).

Для того, чтобы блок с типом отображения `inline` был по центру строки есть свойтво `vertical-align` и значение `middle`. Подробнее про [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

Для того, чтобы крупный `inline` блок вмещался в строку, нужно либо уменьшить высоту изображения, либо увеличить высоту строки с помощью свойства `line-height`.

```css
.article__text {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 22px; /* высота строки */
}
.article__text img {
  display: inline; /* тип отображения */
  vertical-align: middle; /* вертикальное расположение по середине строки */ 
  margin: 0px 0.5em 0px 0.5em; /* отступы слева и справа */
}
```

```html
<div class="article__text">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAAcCAYAAAByDd+UAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAABrSURBVHgB7dXBCYAwDAXQ1DVyriNkKruUHSrYNTKAkoKeFKGUHvR/yCEh8CgUEuYYdxqYiQYHIECAAP8ILinRVgqtOV8z771E5HGnGeyd8HaemLmWmZGq1tn5Mu99frfTDPYOfilAgAA/CB7mMCe1CJgCegAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: о,спасибо большое)